# Return promise value

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to Promise's and I'm trying to wrap my head around getting the value.

Here's an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
API = {
  get: function() {
    return new Promise(function(res) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        res('foo')
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
}

var foo = API.get()

console.log(foo)
```

It's important that `var foo = API.get()` remains as it is.

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: Nothing. What you want is impossible. I recommend to read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ to learn how promises work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a fundamental misunderstanding of asynchronicity.

Answer (score 3):

Promises are still asynchronous. You still can't inspect their value in synchronous code.

You need:

```
API.get().then(function(result) {
    // Resolved value from the Promise object returned by API.get()
    console.log(result);
});
```

`API.get()` returns a *promise object*, you then invoke the `.then()` method on that object.

Another more verbose way would be:

```
var fooPromise = API.get();
fooPromise.then(function(result) { 
    console.log(result); 
});
```

Comment: You get +1 because I didn't know I could have bold text in an answer before :O

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: With using `<pre>`, you can even have *links* in code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Promises are about something happening in the future; you cannot examine their eventual values now unless you are in possession of a time machine.

**I am not suggesting you do this**, but merely for didactic purposes, if you really want your code to function as you seem to, you could redefine `console.log` to be promise-aware:

```
console.log = function() {
    var old_console_dot_log = console.log.bind(console);
    return function(maybe_promise) {
        Promise.resolve(maybe_promise).then(old_console_dot_log);
    };
}();
```

(This version only handles one argument; handling more is left as an exercise.)

Now when you say `console.log(foo)`, it will log the resolved value of `foo`, but only when it is good and ready, one second from now.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. While I think this answer can be improved (in the tone and somewhat in the content) I don't see anything here deserving of a downvote and the log trick is clever since it even preserves order - downvoter - care to explain why?

Comment: Because I thought it was common sense that the `console.log` in the code snippet was merely there just to log the value of the variable `foo`, I'm not looking to override `console.log` are you guys for real.

Comment: @darylm. it's a "what you want is impossible" (which is is) + "thinking outside the box". You got the hard cold truth first I don't understand why you downvoted it.

Comment: @daryl What you want is impossible. Your program can't see into the future.